# Having trouble with a list when both background and after properties are applied

Tags: css, background, overlapping

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/NNbLN/

You can probably see the issue I'm having right away from the demo above. How do I stop the blue background getting applied to the :after element.
In the demo I'm using colours but for production I'm using images, just incase that make any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `padding: 0 10px;` from **li** to **li:after** and add `background: white` to **li:after**.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/neo108/cv6bC/4/

Comment: Thanks, but how do I get padding around the li element then?

Comment: Bingo, I added the padding to the `a` within the `li` - http://jsfiddle.net/jonathandey/YhHvb/